# Excel Find Cell Name

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, vsto

I am trying to write a simple method to find whether the activecell has a namedrange if so, what is it. But it isnt going too well. Here is my code:

```
private void btnH4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveCell.Name == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing");
        return; 
    }
    MessageBox.Show(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveCell.Name.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ActiveCell Name? Do you mean NamedRange or ActiveCell.Address?

Comment: I would like to know the namedrange of the activecell (selected cell).

Comment: Mark it as correct one if you get the answer so that the thread will be closed

Comment: `ActiveCell.Name.Name.ToString()` if the named range is just that one cell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First add `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` reference

add the below line in using section

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Below is the code to get the active cell value

```
//Create excel application object
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
//Create workbook object
Excel.Workbook workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Sample.xlsx");           
//Get the range of active cell
Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)excelApp.Application.ActiveCell;
//Get the cell value
object cellValue = range.Value;
MessageBox.Show(cellValue.ToString());
//Get the address of an active cell
MessageBox.Show(range.Address);
//Get the active cell name 
foreach (Excel.Name item in workBook.Names)
{
    //Compare the active cell address with named range address
    if (item.RefersToRange.Cells.get_Address() == range.Address)
        MessageBox.Show(item.Name);
}
//Close the workbook
workBook.Close();
//Quit the excel application
excelApp.Quit();
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. I am not after the cell value but the cell name. A cell can be given a unique name using Excel Name Manager (under Formula). I am trying to figure out if the Activecell already has a name assigned and if so, report the name.